# Rotate Azure storage account access keys using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage-account, access-keys

I have below requirments.

1. Rotate Storage account access keys (primary_access_key and secondary_access_key  both) via a terraform.
2. add the new regenerated keys as a new version to Secrets created in keyvault for both primary and secondary access keys.

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storageaccrotatekeys"
  resource_group_name      = "accessrotate"
  location                 = "East US"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  public_network_access_enabled = false
}
```

Below `azure_storage_account` resource only contains attributes for `primary_access_key` and `secondary_access_key` that too sensitive values.
I couldn't find any option to rotate keys. Please help
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#import

Answer (score 1):

It may directly be not happening with terraform to rotate the access keys
AFAIK but
please check this customer_managed_key block that can be given in resource
azurerm_storage_account block where auto rotation can be enabled with keyvaultId and version.This customer_managed_key which contains the argument  key_version which is  Optional to mention  the version of Key Vault Key. To enable Automatic Key Rotation you can avoid this option.

- To manually rotate , give the version in the block key_version.
- If separate block is created for customer_managed_key ,  you can provide required argument key_vault_key_id  where in giving version-less key ID will enable auto-rotation of this key.

> **Note:** customer_managed_key needs account_kind to be  StorageV2  UserAssigned as the identity type.

***Code***: from [azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account_customer_managed_key)

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {
resource_group {
  prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }

}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "<resource group>"  
 location = "westus2"
}

provider "azurerm" {
 features {}
 alias = "cloud_operations"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}



resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "ka-examplekv"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name            = "standard"

  purge_protection_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_storage_account.example.identity.0.principal_id
  key_permissions    = ["Get", "Create", "List", "Restore", "Recover", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Purge", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Sign", "Verify"]
  secret_permissions = ["Get"]

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "client" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

  key_permissions    = ["Get", "Create", "Delete", "List", "Restore", "Recover", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Purge", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Sign", "Verify"]
  secret_permissions = ["Get","List"]
}


resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "ka-tfexkey"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048
  key_opts     = ["decrypt", "encrypt", "sign", "unwrapKey", "verify", "wrapKey"]

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.storage,
  ]
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "kaexamplestor"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key" "example" {
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  key_name           = azurerm_key_vault_key.example.name
}
```

[image]
Also check this [time rotaing resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/rotating) which rotates UTC timestamp stored in the Terraform state and recreates resource when the  current time in the locally stored source  is beyond the rotation time. This occurs only when Terraform is executed

**Reference:**
[customer_managed_key  in azurerm_storage_account | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account#customer_managed_key)

Comment: @Abhishek solanki  : Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102381/automate-with-terraform-the-rotation-of-the-specific-secret-stored-in-the-key-va/75105841#75105841) if it helps