# Automate with terraform the rotation of the specific secret stored in the key_vault

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

```
 resource "azurerm_key_vault_managed_storage_account" "example" {
   name                         = var.storage_account_access_key_kv_secret_name
   key_vault_id                 = module.key_vaults.key_vault.id
   storage_account_id           = module.sandbox_storage_blob_storage.storage_account.id
   storage_account_key          = "key1"
   regenerate_key_automatically = var.regenerate_key_automatically
   regeneration_period          = var.regeneration_period
 }
```

This is the error:

Error: creating Managed Storage Account jfrogstorageaccountaccesskey: keyvault.BaseClient#SetStorageAccount: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: {"\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>\r\n404 - File or directory not found.\r\n<style type="text/css">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-si" '\x00' '\x00'} error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value.

Any idea?

I placed the code above

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

*Used below code:*

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_service_principal" "test" {
  # display_name = "Azure Key Vault"
  application_id = "cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093"  #app id of keyvault
}



resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "kavyastorageaccountname"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "kaazkeyv"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name            = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "Delete"
    ]

    storage_permissions = [
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Set",
      "SetSAS",
      "GetSAS",
      "DeleteSAS",
      "Update",
      "RegenerateKey"
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Account Key Operator Service Role"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.test.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_managed_storage_account" "example" {
  name                         = "examplemanagedstorage"
  key_vault_id                 = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  storage_account_id           = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
  storage_account_key          = "key1"
  regenerate_key_automatically = true
  regeneration_period          = "P1D"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.example,
  ]
}
```

- Please note that here application Id is application_id = "cfa8b339-82a2-471a-a3c9-0fc0be7a4093" which is standard for azure public cloud.
  And
  ***Storage Account Key Operator Service Role*** is necessary to create  keyvault managed storage account  .

[image]

- I could execute the code successfully, and the keyvault managed storage account is created successfully, Where ***`regenerate_key_automatically = true`*** ,which automatically rotates the key.

[image]

- So after  azure Key Vault application is given proper role to access  Storage Account , auto regeneration mode set up is successfull.

**Reference:**
[azure-docs/overview-storage-keys.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys.md)