# Using Azure openAI key rotation automation

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-openai

We are planning to do the Azure OpenAI key rotation automatically. How can we achieve this? Do we have terraform resource for this.

```
resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "example" {
  name                = "xxxxx"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "OpenAI"

  sku_name = "S0"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? @Rajnish Kumar Soni

Comment: To create an OpenAI resource you need to use `azurerm_cognitive_account` resource from terraform by providing kind as an "OpenAI" as [shown](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account#argument-reference). Once it is done, use `null_resource` to perform the key rotation. @Rajnish Kumar Soni

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the null_resource part. We do have code to create the openai. I need help on rotation.

Comment: First you need to use this [`data`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external) block to obtain the keys. After that use the `null_resource` available in terraform and pass the open ai resource id under `triggers` block. @Rajnish Kumar Soni

Comment: Using PowerShell scripting, we need to write a script for key rotation and pass it in the terraform provisioner. @Rajnish Kumar Soni

Comment: Creating a Terraform script for Azure OpenAI key rotation involves several steps, particularly if direct support for Azure OpenAI keys is not available in the Terraform AzureRM provider. As of my last update, direct management of Azure OpenAI keys was not a feature provided by the provider, so you'll likely need to use a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is no direct resource present for the Open AI key rotation in terraform. Following a workaround on the requirement, I found below approach to make it work.

As I mentioned in the comments, use `azurerm_cognitive_account` resource from terraform by providing kind as an `"OpenAI"` as [shown](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account#argument-reference).

I tried creating a new open AI account with the below code and the deployment was successful.

```bash
provider  "azurerm"{
  features{}
}
data  "azurerm_resource_group"  "example"  {
    name = "DefaultResourceGroup-EUS"
}
resource  "azurerm_cognitive_account"  "example"  {
    name = "examplesample"
    location = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    kind = "OpenAI"
sku_name = "S0"
}
}
```

[image]

Once it is done, you need to retrieve the keys from the external path. To do that, use `data "external"` block.

How to use it: [Reference](https://sdorsett.github.io/post/2018-12-28-using-an-external-data-source-with-terraform/#:%7E:text=Using%20an%20external%20data%20source%20with%20terraform%201,the%20bottom%20of%20the%20file.%20...%20More%20items)

*Sample data block shown below:*

```bash
data "external" "keys" {
  program = ["sh", "/path/retrieve_sshkey.sh"]
}
```

Now refer this in the `main.tf` terraform resource with `null_resource` block by passing the open ai resource id under `triggers` block and add a `provisioner` as well.

```bash
resource "null_resource" "samplerotation" {
  triggers = {
    open_ai_resource_id = azurerm_cognitive_account.example.id
    }
provisioner "remote-exec" {
 //write a powershell script here and refer the above keys data block here
 }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also follow an other approach with the help of key vault. Store all the keys in the key vault and apply the key rotation from there itself.

To do so, refer the terraform code from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102381/automate-with-terraform-the-rotation-of-the-specific-secret-stored-in-the-key-va) & for CLI approach refer [Github doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys.md).

Comment: thanks @jahnavi i will give this a try.